# Need help figuring out why I can't get the content of a certain textarea element with Javascript for my code playground

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

I'm building a code playground using Code Mirror. My issue is that I'm not able to get the content from the textarea elements I have for html, css, and js. I created a textarea aside from those textarea elements to see if my code for getting the content from a textarea had issues. So in my html, of course I have the textarea tags. I gave this new textarea a class name "txtb" and I created a link with an onclick attribute for a function called "AlertContent()". 
Here is the javascript for the function:

```
function AlertContent(){

alert(document.getElementsByClassName('txtb')[0].value);  

}
```

and guess what, it works. When I type into the textarea element that has the class "txtb", and click the link which calls the function AlertContent() I created, I see a message box appear displaying the text I typed into that textarea. It works. However, when I try to give classes to the textarea elements I'm using with Code Mirror, and use the same function to get the value or content from those textarea elements, I end up getting a blank message box even though there's text (html, css, js) in those textarea elements. All I want to do, is create a function that will get the content of the textarea elements (html, css, js) so then I can save it to my database. I would really appreciate the help. Here's the code I'm using for Code Mirror.

```
<!-- Code Editors -->
<section id="code_editors">
<div id="html" class="code_box">
<h3>HTML</h3>
<form><textarea class="MyHtml" name="htmlcode"></textarea></form>
</div>
<div id="css" class="code_box">
<h3>CSS</h3>
<textarea class="MyCss" name="css"></textarea>
</div>
<div id="js" class="code_box">
<h3>JavaScript</h3>
<textarea class="MyJs" name="js"></textarea>
</div>
</section>
</div>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
<!-- For HTML/XML -->
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
<!-- For CSS -->
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
<!-- For JS -->
<script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>
</div> 
</div> 

<script>    
(function() {

// Base template
var base_tpl =
"<!doctype html>\n" +
"<html>\n\t" +
"<head>\n\t\t" +
"<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\t\t" +
"<title>Test</title>\n\n\t\t\n\t" +
"</head>\n\t" +
"<body>\n\t\n\t" +
"</body>\n" +
"</html>";

 var prepareSource = function() {
 var html = html_editor.getValue(),
 css = css_editor.getValue(),
 js = js_editor.getValue(),
 src = '';
 // HTML
 src = base_tpl.replace('</body>', html + '</body>');

 // CSS
 css = '<style>' + css + '</style>';
 src = src.replace('</head>', css + '</head>');
 // Javascript
 js = '<script>' + js + '<\/script>';
 src = src.replace('</body>', js + '</body>');
 return src;
 };
 var render = function() {
 var source = prepareSource();
 var iframe = document.querySelector('#output iframe'),
 iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;
 iframe_doc.open();
 iframe_doc.write(source);
 iframe_doc.close();
 };
 // EDITORS
 // CM OPTIONS
 var cm_opt = {
 mode: 'text/html',
 gutter: true,
 lineNumbers: true,
 };
 // HTML EDITOR
 var html_box = document.querySelector('#html textarea');
 var html_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(html_box, cm_opt);

 html_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
 render();
 });

 // CSS EDITOR
 cm_opt.mode = 'css';
 var css_box = document.querySelector('#css textarea');
 var css_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(css_box, cm_opt);

 css_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
 render();
 });

 // JAVASCRIPT EDITOR
 cm_opt.mode = 'javascript';
 var js_box = document.querySelector('#js textarea');
 var js_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(js_box, cm_opt);

 js_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
 render();
 });

 // SETTING CODE EDITORS INITIAL CONTENT
 html_editor.setValue('<p>Empty Room</p>');
 css_editor.setValue('body { color: gray; }');
 // RENDER CALL ON PAGE LOAD
 // NOT NEEDED ANYMORE, SINCE WE RELY
 // ON CODEMIRROR'S onChange OPTION THAT GETS
 // TRIGGERED ON setValue
 // render();
 // NOT SO IMPORTANT - IF YOU NEED TO DO THIS
 // THEN THIS SHOULD GO TO CSS
 /*
 Fixing the Height of CodeMirror.
 You might want to do this in CSS instead
 of JS and override the styles from the main
 codemirror.css
*/
 var cms = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror');
 for (var i = 0; i < cms.length; i++) {
 cms[i].style.position = 'absolute';
 cms[i].style.top = '30px';
 cms[i].style.bottom = '0';
 cms[i].style.left = '0';
 cms[i].style.right = '0';
 cms[i].style.height = '100%';
 }
 /*cms = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror-scroll');
 for (i = 0; i < cms.length; i++) {
 cms[i].style.height = '100%';
 }*/
 }());
 // Basically adding to the CM Options
 cm_opt['extraKeys'] = {
 Tab: function(instance) {
 if (inst.somethingSelected())
 CodeMirror.commands.indentMore(inst);
 else
 CodeMirror.commands.insertTab(inst);
 }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: I suppose CodeMirror is not really using the original textareas but is replacing them with other HTML content to be able to achieve all the features it has. For example you can not have text with different colors in a regular textarea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the `get_value()` that is provided on the editors? For example, `html_editor.getValue()`

Here is an example page doing just that to alert what you write in the CodeMirror textarea when you click the respective editor's button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>CodeMirror</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Code Editors -->
    <section id="code_editors">
        <div id="html" class="code_box">
            <h3>HTML</h3>
            <form><textarea class="MyHtml" name="htmlcode"></textarea></form>
            <button onclick="viewHTML()">Alert this HTML</button>
        </div>
        <div id="css" class="code_box">
            <h3>CSS</h3>
            <textarea class="MyCss" name="css"></textarea>
            <button onclick="viewCSS()">Alert this CSS</button>
        </div>
        <div id="js" class="code_box">
            <h3>JavaScript</h3>
            <textarea class="MyJs" name="js"></textarea>
            <button onclick="viewJS()">Alert this JS</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div id="output">
        <iframe></iframe>
    </div>

    <script src="http://codemirror.net/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <!-- For HTML/XML -->
    <script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
    <script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/htmlmixed/htmlmixed.js"></script>
    <!-- For CSS -->
    <script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/css/css.js"></script>
    <!-- For JS -->
    <script src="http://codemirror.net/mode/javascript/javascript.js"></script>

    <script>    
    (function() {
        // Base template
        var base_tpl =
        "<!doctype html>\n" +
        "<html>\n\t" +
        "<head>\n\t\t" +
        "<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n\t\t" +
        "<title>Test</title>\n\n\t\t\n\t" +
        "</head>\n\t" +
        "<body>\n\t\n\t" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>";

        window.viewHTML = function() {
            alert(html_editor.getValue());
        }

        window.viewCSS = function() {
            alert(css_editor.getValue());
        }

        window.viewJS = function() {
            alert(js_editor.getValue());
        }

        var prepareSource = function() {
            var html = html_editor.getValue(),
                css = css_editor.getValue(),
                js = js_editor.getValue(),
                src = '';

            // HTML
            src = base_tpl.replace('</body>', html + '</body>');

            // CSS
            css = '<style>' + css + '</style>';
            src = src.replace('</head>', css + '</head>');

            // Javascript
            js = '<script>' + js + '<\/script>';
            src = src.replace('</body>', js + '</body>');

            return src;
        };

        var render = function() {
            var source = prepareSource();
            var iframe = document.querySelector('#output iframe'),
            iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument;

            iframe_doc.open();
            iframe_doc.write(source);
            iframe_doc.close();
        };

        // EDITORS
        // CM OPTIONS
        var cm_opt = {
            mode: 'text/html',
            gutter: true,
            lineNumbers: true,
        };

        // HTML EDITOR
        var html_box = document.querySelector('#html textarea');
        var html_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(html_box, cm_opt);

        html_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
            render();
        });

        // CSS EDITOR
        cm_opt.mode = 'css';
        var css_box = document.querySelector('#css textarea');
        var css_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(css_box, cm_opt);

        css_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
            render();
        });

        // JAVASCRIPT EDITOR
        cm_opt.mode = 'javascript';
        var js_box = document.querySelector('#js textarea');
        var js_editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(js_box, cm_opt);

        js_editor.on('change', function (inst, changes) {
            render();
        });

        // SETTING CODE EDITORS INITIAL CONTENT
        html_editor.setValue('<p>Empty Room</p>');
        css_editor.setValue('body { color: gray; }');
        js_editor.setValue('var x = \'10\';');
        // RENDER CALL ON PAGE LOAD
        // NOT NEEDED ANYMORE, SINCE WE RELY
        // ON CODEMIRROR'S onChange OPTION THAT GETS
        // TRIGGERED ON setValue
        // render();
        // NOT SO IMPORTANT - IF YOU NEED TO DO THIS
        // THEN THIS SHOULD GO TO CSS
        /*
        Fixing the Height of CodeMirror.
        You might want to do this in CSS instead
        of JS and override the styles from the main
        codemirror.css
        */
        /*
        var cms = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror');
        for (var i = 0; i < cms.length; i++) {
            cms[i].style.position = 'absolute';
            cms[i].style.top = '30px';
            cms[i].style.bottom = '0';
            cms[i].style.left = '0';
            cms[i].style.right = '0';
            cms[i].style.height = '100%';
        }
        */
        /*cms = document.querySelectorAll('.CodeMirror-scroll');
        for (i = 0; i < cms.length; i++) {
            cms[i].style.height = '100%';
        }*/

        // Basically adding to the CM Options
        cm_opt['extraKeys'] = {
            Tab: function(instance) {
            if (inst.somethingSelected())
                CodeMirror.commands.indentMore(inst);
            else
                CodeMirror.commands.insertTab(inst);
            }
        }
    }());

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```